# Gorgosaurus (rare type) is level 6 right away?

Tags: jurassic-world-alive

I have had enough DNA to create a Rare type Dinosaur, a Gorgosaurus. 
It don;t understand why he is right away a level 6, because my Common types I have to level up from 1 to 2 to 3 etc.

Also I only need 100 DNA to get Gorgosaurus to the next level. 
Is it becuase he is a rare that he skips levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended behavior.

Lab creations of...

- Common types (50 DNA) start at level 1
- Rare types (100 DNA) start at level 6
- Epic types (150 DNA) start at level 11

You have found some pros and cons already. While it is harder to initially create a rare or epic dino (you get less DNA from darts and need more DNA to start creating a dino) you start at a higher level and can use rare or epic dinos more efficiently in the arena.

Comment: Thanks for that list. He is indeed mij first non-common I created. And he is indeed very good in battle.